# Condition for a contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-mapping

Consider a mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^N \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$, with $F = (F_1,...,F_N)$, and with $F_i$ increasing in all its arguments for all $i$. Let $(x_{1}^{1},x_{2}^{1},...,x_{N}^{1})=(x_{1}^{0}+\Delta,x_{2}^{0}+\Delta,...,x_{N}^{0}+\Delta)$ for $\Delta > 0$. If $$||F\left(x^{1}\right)-F\left(x^{0}\right)||<\Delta$$ for any such $x^1,x^0$. If $F$ is differentiable then we can show that its Jacobian is substochastic and hence its spectral radius is lower than one, which implies that $F$ is a contraction. Is there a more direct way of showing that $F$ is a contraction without going through the Jacobian?

Comment: $$\|F(x^1)-F(x^0)\|_2\leq \|F(x^0+\|x^1-x^0\|_\infty) -F(x^0)\|_2 < \|x^1-x^0\|_\infty \leq \|x^1-x^0\|_2$$ I think you can show it is a contraction if you are more careful with this argument

Comment: I see that the second inequality holds because of the displayed condition I gave, and I understand the third inequality, but I don't know how to show the first inequality for general $x^0$ and $x^1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think it is wrong up to some constant factor perhaps. You can first consider the case $x^1-x^0 \geq0$ (i.e. $x^1_i-x^0_i\geq 0$ for all $i$). Then you can handle the general case by triangle inequality

Comment: Thanks for that, but I fear that triangle inequality creates slack that prevents showing the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer mimics the proof of the Blackwell's sufficient condition for contraction (it is along the lines Andrew gave in the comments to the original post).

Suppose that all norms are infinity norms: $\left\| x \right\|_{\infty} = \max_{i} \left| x_i \right| $, so that the condition in the original post is
\begin{align*}
\left\| F\left(x^{1}\right) - F\left(x^{0}\right) \right\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda \Delta,
\end{align*}
for some $0 < \lambda < 1$. (Here I use a stronger condition than in the original post.)
Observe that since $x^{1} > x^{0}$ and $F_{i}$ is monotone for each $i$, we can write the above condition as
\begin{align}
F_{i}\left(x^{1}\right) < F_{i}\left(x^{0}\right) + \lambda\Delta, \; i = 1, \dots, N. \quad (1)
\end{align}

Now take any two vectors $x$ and $y$. Let $\Delta \equiv \left\| x - y \right\|_{\infty}$ and $\delta \equiv \left( \Delta, \dots, \Delta \right)$.

First, we have $x \leq y + \delta$. Then, for each $i = 1,\dots, N$ we have
\begin{align*}
F_{i} \left( x \right) \leq F_{i} \left( y + \delta \right)
\leq F_{i} \left( y \right) + \lambda\Delta.
\quad (2)
\end{align*}
The first inequality is due to monotonicity of $F_{i}$, and the second inequality uses condition $(1)$.

Similarly, we have $y \leq x + \delta$ and so for each $i = 1,\dots,N$,
\begin{align*}
F_{i} \left( y \right) \leq F_{i} \left( x + \delta \right)
\leq F_{i} \left( x \right) + \lambda\Delta.
\quad (3)
\end{align*}

Combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get
$\left| F_{i} (x) - F_{i}(y) \right| \leq \lambda\Delta$ for all $i = 1, \dots, N$. This implies that $\left\| F_{i} (x) - F_{i}(y) \right\|_{\infty} \leq \lambda \Delta = \lambda \left\| x - y \right\|_{\infty}$. Thus, $F$ is a contraction mapping.